# Assign categories based on percentages in a javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects (<{"SOME_LOCATION_ID": IT's VALUE}>) like:

```
let data = [{"12":132},{"229":133.84},{"174":137},{"2038":137.04},{"723":137.78},{"521":138.88},{"120":139.7},{"84":139.99},{"218":143.9},{"926":144.59},{"203":145.07},{"210":146.46},{"712":147.81},{"221":150.54},{"516":152.7},{"219":154.41},{"202":155.99},{"1018":158},{"199":158.63},{"230":158.81}];
```

I have a categories object like this:

```
const parts = {
    "Category1": 0.2,    // 20%
    "Category2": 0.2,    // 20%
    "Category3": 0.2,    // 20%
    "Category4": 0.2,    // 20%
    "Category5": 0.1,    // 10%
    "Category6": 0.1     // 10%
};

//All these add upto 1 (100%)
```

I want to get my output as an array of objects something that looks like this, percentages in comments

```
[
    {"12":132, "category": "Category1"},                // First 20%
    {"229":133.84, "category": "Category1"},            // First 20%
    {"174":137, "category": "Category1"},               // First 20%
    {"2038":137.04, "category": "Category1"},           // First 20%
    {"723":137.78, "category": "Category2"},            // Second 20%
    {"521":138.88, "category": "Category2"},            // Second 20%
    {"120":139.7, "category": "Category2"},             // Second 20%
    {"84":139.99, "category": "Category2"},             // Second 20%
    {"218":143.9, "category": "Category3"},             // Third 20%
    {"926":144.59, "category": "Category3"},            // Third 20%
    {"203":145.07, "category": "Category3"},            // Third 20%
    {"210":146.46, "category": "Category3"},            // Third 20%
    {"712":147.81, "category": "Category4"},            // Fourth 20%
    {"221":150.54, "category": "Category4"},            // Fourth 20%
    {"516":152.7, "category": "Category4"},             // Fourth 20%
    {"219":154.41, "category": "Category4"},            // Fourth 20%
    {"202":155.99, "category": "Category5"},            // Fifth 10%
    {"1018":158, "category": "Category5"},              // Fifth 10%
    {"199":158.63, "category": "Category6"},            // Sixth 10%
    {"230":158.81, "category": "Category6"}             // Sixth 10%
]
```

This example has only 20 objects in the original array. What can I do to lets say if it has uneven number of objects (like an odd number of objects like 23 or 57, etc.)

Comment: Whats have you tried so far ? Please show show us your attempt

Comment: @AlwaysHelping I tried with iterating over Object.values(parts) and Object.keys(parts) to divide the array based on them, but couldn't really take it forward from there

Comment: Well, what is the objective here? If you want to simply divide the `data` into `categories` where each `category` has X number of items. And this X is a percentage, then what do you want to do when the total number of items is say 22 where 20% would be 4.4. How do you want to deal with the decimal part? Will you pick up 4 items or 5 (since there is no way to pick up 4.4 items)? Or is it something totally different that you want to do. It is best to post your attempts.

Comment: @endeavour Yes, I'd want to pickup five items, if it has 4.4 and eventually the last category (Category6)  can have whichever are remaining

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another approach:

```
let data = [{"12":132},{"229":133.84},{"174":137},{"2038":137.04},{"723":137.78},{"521":138.88},{"120":139.7},{"84":139.99},{"218":143.9},{"926":144.59},{"203":145.07},{"210":146.46},{"712":147.81},{"221":150.54},{"516":152.7},{"219":154.41},{"202":155.99},{"1018":158},{"199":158.63},{"230":158.81}];

const parts = {
    "Category1": 0.2,    // 20%
    "Category2": 0.2,    // 20%
    "Category3": 0.2,    // 20%
    "Category4": 0.2,    // 20%
    "Category5": 0.1,    // 10%
    "Category6": 0.1     // 10%
};

let result = []; // holds the result
let cnt = data.length; // store initial length
let takeCnt; // counter for the items to take from the data array for each category

for(key in parts){ //iterate over the categories
    takeCnt = Math.ceil(cnt*parts[key]); //calculate how many items we take
    for(let x=0; x<takeCnt; x++){ //iterate over the data
        resultItem = data.pop(); //take and remove the item
        if(resultItem){
            resultItem[key] = parts[key]; //create result object
            result.push(resultItem); //assign result to final array
        }
    }
}

console.log(result);
```

And here is a fiddle to play around with it: https://jsfiddle.net/Postlagerkarte/pcqbfx8t/

Comment: This helps. 
Changed `pop()` to `shift()` to get them in the right order.
Changed  `resultItem[key] = parts[key];` to `resultItem["category"] = key;`
Thank you